# WMS Server scale problem

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm new to the environment QGIS, and my question and problem is when changing a layer coming from http://ide.cime.es/menorca/wms/base_referencia/

I want to load the 1-> 86 layer and at first everything works well, the problem comes when scaling to work at street level -- when I get to the scale of 1: 332,000 you can no longer see all the map.

Do you know why it may be that you no longer see anything?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [GetCapabilities document](http://ide.cime.es/menorca/wms/base_referencia/?request=getcapabilities) for the WMS you will see that many of the layers specify a maximum and minimum scale that they will be displayed at:

```
<Layer queryable="1">
<Name>RE007TOP_top100</Name>
<Title>Rústic. Toponímia 1:100.000</Title>
<Abstract>
Toponímia 1:100000 de Menorca. Aquesta capa s'ha creat a partir de la revisió, classificació i modificació diverses fonts d'informació de topònims del Consell Insular. S'ha creat per ser utlitizada com a base de referència de la IDE Menorca.
</Abstract>
<Style>
<Name>default</Name>
<Title>Rústic. Toponímia 1:100.000</Title>
<LegendURL xmlns="">
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://ide.cime.es/menorca/legends/base_referencia/RE007TOP_top100.png"/>
</LegendURL>
</Style>
<MinScaleDenominator>48192.909226</MinScaleDenominator>
<MaxScaleDenominator>103944.397321</MaxScaleDenominator>
<MetadataURL xmlns="" type="TC211">
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://ide.cime.es/menorca/geonetwork/srv/en/iso19139.xml?id=122"/>
</MetadataURL>
<DataURL xmlns="">
<Format>application/zip</Format>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://ide.cime.es/menorca/data/RE007TOP_top100.zip"/>
</DataURL>
</Layer>
```

These used to be called ScaleHints which gave the impression they were advisory bu they have always been mandatory, if you request the layer outside these scales nothing will be returned.

So I would say the WMS is working fine.